# How to run multiple instances(datasets) from same CPLEX model?

Tags: database, dataset, cplex, opl

I have a MIP model in CPLEX as a mod file. I have datasets in multiple '.txt' files. Is there a way to automate the process in CPLEX to solve the model for many instances. Currently, I run the model every single time for every instance. I have my instances as "M1_D1.txt", "M2_D1.txt",...."M100_D10.txt". However, the model to solve is the same.

In Matlab, it is easier to automate the process. But I could not find anywhere how to automate in CPLEX.

```
   define variables
   retrieve data from .dat file

   define objective function
   define constraints
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a main block (flow control)
Here is an example:

sub.mod

```
float maxOfx = ...;
dvar float x;

maximize x;
subject to {
  x<=maxOfx;
 }

execute
{
  writeln("x= ",x);
}
```

try1.dat

```
maxOfx=1;
```

try2.dat

```
maxOfx=2;
```

and then

main.mod

```
{string} datFiles=...;

main {
      var source = new IloOplModelSource("sub.mod");
      var cplex = new IloCplex();
      var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);

      for(var datFile in thisOplModel.datFiles)
      {
      var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);

      var data2= new IloOplDataSource(datFile);

      opl.addDataSource(data2);
      opl.generate();

      if (cplex.solve()) {  
         opl.postProcess();
         var o=new IloOplOutputFile("res"+datFile+".txt");
         o.writeln("OBJ = " + cplex.getObjValue());
         o.close();
         writeln("OBJ = " + cplex.getObjValue());
      } else {
         writeln("No solution");
      }
     opl.end();
    }  

    }
```

main.dat

```
datFiles={"Try1.dat","try2.dat"};
```

In command line oplrun main.mod main.dat
In the IDE, you need to have main.mod and main.dat in a run configuration

Comment: Many Thanks to you sir. You saved a lot of my time. Really appreciate it. :)